# Coverity Command Line Commands / API documentation

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, coverity

I'm getting started with Coverity with a new job that I have but I'm having a terrible time trying to find documentation around this tool. I'm looking for command line tools / documentation for how to run coverity for scripting purposes.

The end goal is to run it in Jenkins (yes I know Jenkins has coverity support) but I need Jenkinsfiles for Jenkins 2 and Coverity isn't there yet. So I'm using command line arguments in that Jenkinsfile script in order to run the coverity tests. I just cannot seem to find solid coverity documentation (how do people know what cov-build and such mean)

Comment: Did you have any results about this? Trying to do the same and ended up here, but there is no answer on the question yet...

Answer (score 1):

I have Coverity analysis installed in C:/cygwin/home/peterd/cov-analysis-win64-8.7.1 and thus can access documentation in a web browser at file:///C:/cygwin/home/peterd/cov-analysis-win64-8.7.1/doc/index.html

Specifically, the command reference is at file:///C:/cygwin/home/peterd/cov-analysis-win64-8.7.1/doc/en/cov_command_ref.html

The same command references should also be available by passing --help to any command.

Other parts of the documentation provide an architectural overview.